Determining if feature occurs between single point and polyline using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
I'm looking to perform an analysis that outputs whether or not something lies between two points. This specific example would be: does a stream occur between a point of interest and a road. The Near Tool gives distance and direction of nearest stream, but I'd be looking for a binary output of "yes, a stream occurs" or "no, a stream does not occur" between a point and a road feature. Then, of course, repeated for every point within my point shapefile.
My initial thought is that I must be able to generate a series of lines from the points to the interested line feature, and then use the intersect tool to count intersect occurrences between the new line features and the streams.

Add xy coordinates to points. In near to line tick location. Use xy to line to create lines from points table. 2 selections after will complete the task. Between term though needs more clarity

Are you using the Near tool of ArcGIS Pro or something else?

PolyGeo: Yes sorry, program is ArcGIS Pro, most recent version.

Felix: are you asking for more clarity from me? I assume the process you described would create a new line shapefile that would give me straight lines between the two points of interest. Thanks.

There's mathematically an infinite number of places a stream could pass "between" a point and a road (polyline). Maybe you mean whether it crosses the line that extends from the point to the nearest point on the road?

Thanks Paulo, yes thank you for rewording my question in a clearer way. Beautifully stated, that is exactly what I am attempting to measure.
